# Trouble fetching local json file

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to get back data from a local json file. Here is my js:

```
const apiURL = "../hoteldata.json";

//Go fetch it and then wait for a response.
fetch(apiURL)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((myList) => {
    //Once it comes back, display it to the console.
    console.log(myList);
    
    
    
}); //end of "then" fat arrow function
```

I get a 404 response back. I cannot figure out what I've done wrong.

Comment: Are you sure the path and the filename are correct?

Comment: @Clvckl3s it's a local javascript file ran on Live Server through vs code

Comment: How are you serving the json file?

Comment: What's the URL of the HTML document? What's the URL of the JSON file? What URLs are actually being requested by the browser (look in the Network tab of the developers tools)?

Comment: It's a 404 error, Which means the file is not found.

Comment: @Quentin Path of json: `hotel/hoteldata.json` Path of index.html: `hotel/index.html` Path of request: `http://127.0.0.1:5501/hoteldata.json`

Answer (score 0):

Reset VS code and it started working. Not sure what actually broke it but it is working now.